# Slice a DT table after other filters have been applied

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have larger shiny app where I use DT to view, sort, filter, etc. a dataset. DT works great! The app has filters set to adjust the data **before** it is passed to DT for rendering (e.g., Data Filter and Data Slice in the screenshot below). The Table Slice functionality, however, does not yet work.

However, it would also be useful to slice the data shown in the DT table **after** different DT filters have been applied (e.g., sorting on price like in the screenshot below and just rendering the top 5, 10, 1,000).

My first attempt is shown in the reproducible example below. The goal is to slice the DT table **after** it has been sorted on price so the user can see just the top 5 or 10 rows. In the example this works fine the first time the user changes `stop_index`. However, changing `stop_index`, changes the table, and thus `input$my_table_rows_all`.

What I'd want is for the user to be able to move `stop_index` around multiple times and the value 20 stays at the top of the table and no NAs are added. Similarly, if the user moves around `start_index` multiple time, 11 stays at the bottom and no NAs are added.

[image: Radiant Data > View tab]

Are there any other/better option than using `proxy`? I could get close to what I'm looking by changing the `pageLength` option. That is less effective, however, if the user wants just the top 50,000 customers on some metric (e.g., CLV). Also, that would always start the table at index 1 (0). What if the users wants 10,000:5,0000, for example?

I also thought about a draggable filter like you can have in DT for numeric variables but then based on the row-index of the table and not the values of the variable shown in the table.

[image]

As always, glad to hear any suggestions you might have.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(row_index = 1:10, price = 11:20)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Slice Rows Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("start_index", "Start index:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 1),
      sliderInput("stop_index", "Stop index:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("my_table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    ## No rows are shown when rownames = FALSE - strange (DT 0.25)
    # datatable(dat, rownames = FALSE, options = list(saveState = TRUE, order=list(list(2, "desc"))))
    datatable(dat, rownames = TRUE, options = list(saveState = TRUE, order=list(list(2, "desc"))))
  })

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("my_table")

  observe({
    print(input$my_table_rows_all)
  })

  observeEvent(c(input$start_index, input$stop_index), {
    req(input$my_table_rows_all)
    start_ind <- input$start_index
    stop_ind <- input$stop_index
    ind <- input$my_table_rows_all[start_ind:stop_ind]
    replaceData(proxy, dat[ind, ,drop=FALSE])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below what the example app would look like after moving `stop_index` to 7 and then back to 8. As you can see, the top value is no longer 20 and NAs have been added. That makes sense because `my_table_rows_all` was change, which is why I'm looking for an alternate approach.

[image]

Comment: Quick question: What would you want to happen when a user sorts / filters the table after they have changed the indices? If the current displayed indices are let's say 5 - 9, should sort sort them from 9-5? And what would happen if you then update the sliders again? Which data should then be shown?

You can see this gets complicated, so maybe you could also opt for saying that when sorting / filtering happens the index sliders will reset, which would be cleaner.

Let me know what you think and I can see if I can come up with something :)

Comment: I see your point. The sorting and filtering with DT would happen first. The sliders for Start and Stop would select the final (total) size of the table to show in the shiny app.

So DTs filtering, search, sorting, etc. would have access to the full data, but the pieces shared with the shiny app would be sliced by the sliders.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reactive to filter your data with the slider inputs and just replace data inside `ObserveEvent`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(row_index = 1:10, price = 11:20)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Slice Rows Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("start_index", "Start index:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 1),
      sliderInput("stop_index", "Stop index:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("my_table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    ## No rows are shown when rownames = FALSE - strange (DT 0.25)
    # datatable(dat, rownames = FALSE, options = list(saveState = TRUE, order=list(list(2, "desc"))))
    datatable(dat, rownames = TRUE, options = list(saveState = TRUE, order=list(list(2, "desc"))))
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("my_table")
  
  observe({
    print(input$my_table_rows_all)
  })
  
  dat_f <- reactive({
    dat <- dat[input$start_index:input$stop_index, ]
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$start_index, input$stop_index), {

    replaceData(proxy, dat_f())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @juanbarq. This approach still slices before, or doesn't take into account, what sorting or filter the user might have done in DT. What I'm looking for requires something like input$my_table_rows_all. However, input$my_table_rows_all "forgets" about the existence of the other rows once the start and stop indexes have been applied.